# How remove DRUPAL manually from Plesk

Tags: drupal, plesk

during some test I installed DRUPAL twice on my server using the PLESK application installer. The I removed the drupal files and the .htaccess  manually and I deleted the drupal DB. After that I realized there was an unistaller link an the PLEK panel...  but it was too late.

Now PLESK continue to see  drupal installed... and I need help to  complete the drupal removal manually.  Can You help me ?

On the net I have found this link: http://kb.parallels.com/en/112733 but I'm not sure on the steps to do...

Anyway I have the resource id.

Can you help me ?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to have access to all of your files through an FTP browser. Recursively set the permissions for every folder and file on your website as 0777(owner, group and others; read write and execute). I am not sure what you use, but I use winSCP, and to recursively set permissions you select all the files and folders, right click properties, and type in the octal value of 0777, and then click set group owner and permissions recursively. after all of the permissions are 0777 you will need to delete every file. You can accomplish this by selecting every drupal related file and folder. Else contact plesk.

Good Luck